# Slow MySQL Queries on new Server, switching from Joyent to rimuhosting

Tags: mysql

I recently switched servers because Joyent is ending their service soon.  But the queries on rimuhosting seem to take significantly longer (2-6 times).  But there's a huge variance in behavior: most queries run .02 seconds or less and then sometimes those same exact queries take .5 seconds or more.  Both servers were running mySQL and PHP (similar version but not the same exact number).

The server load is 20-40% Idle for the CPU.  Most of the memory is being used, but they tell me that's normal.  The tech support tells me it's not swapping:
Here's what it looks like right now: (though memory usage will increase to near max eventually, like last time)
Mem:   1513548k total,  1229316k used,   284232k free,    63540k buffers
Swap:   131064k total,        0k used,   131064k free,   981420k cached

SQL max connections is set to 400.

So, why am i getting these super slow queries, sometimes?
Here is an example of a query that is sometimes .01 second and sometimes greater then 1 second:
SELECT   (!attacked AND (firstLoginDate > 1348703469 )) as protected,
            id, universe.uid, universe.name AS obj_name,`top`,`left`, guilds.name as alliance,
            rotate,what, player_data.first, player_data.last, 
            aid AS gid, (aid=1892 AND aid>0) as am,
            fleet LIKE '%Turret%' AS turret,
            startLeft, startTop, endLeft, endTop, duration, startTime, movetype,
            moving,speed, defend, hp, lastAttack>1349740269 AS ra    FROM universe LEFT JOIN player_data ON universe.uid=player_data.uid
            LEFT JOIN guilds ON aid=guilds.gid 
            WHERE (  sector='21_82' OR  sector='22_82' OR  sector='21_83' OR  sector='22_83' ) OR
            ( universe.uid=1568425485 AND ( upgrading=1 OR building=1 ))

Yes, I do have indexes on all the appropriate columns.  And all 3 tables featured above are InnoDB tables, which means they are only row locked, not table locked.

but this is interesting: (new server)
Innodb_row_lock_time_avg    400  The average time to acquire a row lock, in milliseconds.
Innodb_row_lock_time_max    4,010    The maximum time to acquire a row lock, in milliseconds.
Innodb_row_lock_waits   31   The number of times a row lock had to be waited for.

why does it take so long to get a row lock?
my old server was able to get the row lock faster:
Innodb_row_lock_time_avg    26   The average time to acquire a row lock, in milliseconds.

Here's the new server:
Opened_tables   5,500   (in just 2 hours) The number of tables that have been opened. If opened tables is big, your table cache value is probably too small.
table cache 256
table locks waited 3,302 (in just 2 hours)

Here is the old server:
Opened_tables   420
table cache 64

Does that makes sense?  If I increase the table Cache will that alleviate things?

Note: i have 1.5 GB on this server

Here is the explain
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key      key_len    ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  universe    index_merge uidwhat,uid,uidtopleft,upgrading,building,sector    sector,uid  38,8    NULL    116 Using sort_union(sector,uid); Using where
1   SIMPLE  player_data ref mainIndex   mainIndex   8   jill_sp.universe.uid    1
1   SIMPLE  guilds  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 8   jill_sp.player_data.aid 1

Comment: Note: both servers show the following: innodb table locks is On

Comment: Have you run tuning-primer.sh (http://www.day32.com/MySQL/tuning-primer.sh) in order to ensure your mysql settings are proper? Also, have you enabled the slow query log and are there any entries in it? What are the results of running EXPLAIN on the query you provided?

Comment: Here is the explain
id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra
1 SIMPLE universe index_merge uidwhat,uid,uidtopleft,upgrading,building,sector sector,uid 38,8 NULL 116 Using sort_union(sector,uid); Using where
1 SIMPLE player_data ref mainIndex mainIndex 8 jill_sp.universe.uid 1  
1 SIMPLE guilds eq_ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 8 jill_sp.player_data.aid 1

Comment: Okay, i tried the tuning-primer.sh.  it suggested I increase: max_heap_table_size
tmp_table_size
table_cache
And I did.  But it's still not working. I'm still getting bad performance.

Comment: Can you post the results of the following: 
 1) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb%'\G 
 2) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G 
 3) SHOW CREATE TABLE universe\G 
 4) SHOW CREATE TABLE player\G?